# Device registration using backendless

Tags: android, backendless

I'm registering my device ob backendless but it gave error:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not register device on Backendless server: Permission denied (missing INTERNET permission?)

However i have also added `INTERNET` and `ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE` permissions in `manifest file`. I don't know why it gave error.
The permissions are:

```
user-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" 
user-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"
```

Here is my java file code:

```
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Backendless.initApp(this,AppKey,SecretKey,Version);
        Backendless.Messaging.registerDevice(gcmSenderID, "default", new AsyncCallback<Void>() {
            @Override
            public void handleResponse(Void response) {
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"Registered", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void handleFault(BackendlessFault fault) {
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"fault: "+fault.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

    }
```

Comment: It's `<uses-permission>`, not `<user-permission>`.

Comment: @MikeM.  thanks, but now it gave this error in handle fault method, 'Not Allowed to start service Intent {act=com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTER pkg=com.google.android.gsf(has extras)} without permission com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE

Comment: post your manifests file code

Comment: @NKmewara BTW issue has been solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```